# Any possible way to change iOS mobile app all UILabel colour at one place?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have to change all UILabel colour at one place whenever application loads. I know that there is a way to change the colour for UILabel separately by setting textColor. As this is time taking process to change all UILabel individual programatically or by using StoryBoard.

I need to know the way to make it simple by adding textColor in one place to change the label color. Even for changing Controller label colour is fineSimilar eg. By the means of UILabel categories.

Any snippet will helpful for me to achieve this. Code for individual Controller's UIlabel colour is fine.

Comment: create a custom class of UILabel and set it all the label in storyboard, change the text color in custom class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to handle this. You probably shouldn't use the tintColor property, since Apple intends that as a visual cue for items that are tappable.

I'd suggest creating a custom subclass of `UILabel`. Let's call it `ColorChangingLabel`. Define a `NotificationCenter` notification name `labelColorChanged`, and when you broadcast that notifictation, add a key/value pair `textColor` to the notification's userInfo that contains your new text color. You could also add an optional background color key/value pair if you want to be able to change that. (In fact, you could add a whole suite of different key/value pairs that would let you change different properties of your custom labels.)

In your custom UILabel subclass:

- Define a function `addLabelColorChangedObserver()`. Have that
  function call the `NotificationCenter` to add an observer for your
  `labelColorChanged` notification that looks for a `textColor` in the notification's `userInfo` and uses that color to change the label's text color.
- Override `init(frame:)` and `init(coder:)` and have those methods
  call your `addLabelColorChangedObserver()` function.
- Implement a deinit method for your UILabel subclass that removes its
  observer.

In your app, when you want labels to change their colors,  post a notification with a `userInfo` dictionary containing the new text color.

Once you've done all that, go through all of your app's storyboards select each label, and use the "identity inspector" to change the class of the object to your custom `ColorChangingLabel` class. That should do it.

### Edit:

If you want to be able to target color changes on a view controller by view controller basis, you could set up your labels to have an `owningViewController` property, and when it's set, they would add the `owningViewController` as the `object` parameter when they add themselves as observers of the `labelColorChanged` notification. Then, to tell a single view controller's labels to change their color, you'd send a notification with the target view controller as the `object` parameter.

The tricky bit here would be setting the `owningViewController` property on the labels. You'd want a method to be able to set that up automatically when your view controller's views are loaded. Perhaps in your view controller's viewDidLoad method you'd call a method that would recursively walk the view controller hierarchy, setting itself as the `owningViewController` for all `ColorChangingLabel`s.

### EDIT 2:

I implemented a CustomLabel class as described above. Here's the code:

```
//
//  CustomLabel.swift
//  CustomLabel
//
//  Created by Duncan Champney on 4/20/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Duncan Champney. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

let labelColorChangedNotice: NSNotification.Name  = NSNotification.Name("labelColorChangedNotice")
let textColorKey = "textColor"
let backgroundColorKey = "backgroundColor"

class CustomLabel: UILabel {
  static var classLabelColorChangeObserver: Any!

  static var startingTextColor: UIColor?
  static var startingTextBGColor: UIColor?

  override class func initialize() {
    
    //Have the CustomLabel class add an observer to record changes to the text color and/or background color even if there are no CustomLabel instances on-screen.
    classLabelColorChangeObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: labelColorChangedNotice,
       object: nil,
       queue: nil ) {
        notification in
        if let textColor = notification.userInfo?[textColorKey] as? UIColor {
          CustomLabel.startingTextColor = textColor
        }
        if let backgroundColor = notification.userInfo?[backgroundColorKey] as? UIColor {
          CustomLabel.startingTextBGColor = backgroundColor
        }
    }
  }
  
  var labelColorChangeObserver: Any?

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    labelColorChangeObserver = addLabelColorChangedObserver()
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    labelColorChangeObserver = addLabelColorChangedObserver()
  }
  
  deinit {
    if let labelColorChangeObserver = labelColorChangeObserver {
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer: labelColorChangeObserver)
    }
  }
  
  func addLabelColorChangedObserver() {
    if let startingTextColor = CustomLabel.startingTextColor {
      self.textColor = startingTextColor
    }
    if let startingTextBGColor = CustomLabel.startingTextBGColor {
      self.backgroundColor = startingTextBGColor
    }
    labelColorChangeObserver =  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: labelColorChangedNotice,
      object: nil,
      queue: nil ) {
        [weak self] //Use a capture list to avoid a retain cycle
        notification in
        
        //Once we're in the notification's closure, capture self strongly, or bail if it's nil.
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
          return
        }
        
        //If we've been given a textColor, install it in the label.
        if let textColor = notification.userInfo?[textColorKey] as? UIColor {
          strongSelf.textColor = textColor
        }
        //If we've been given a backgroundColor, install it in the label.
        if let backgroundColor = notification.userInfo?[backgroundColorKey] as? UIColor {
          strongSelf.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I need to post the NSNotification for the observer? Do I need to call for all UILabel separately?

Comment: No. If you create a subclass of UILabel that adds a listener for your notification, all labels that are on-screen will change their color when you broadcast the notification. Note, however, that labels created afterwords will not. You should probably define a static variable to hold the current label color, have the class observe the same notification and change the static variable, and have the init methods use the static variable to set the label color

Comment: Thank you for giving efficient approach for manage UI. I can use this method for customisation of view's dynamically. I will get back to you once I integrate all these above changes in my app.